# C++ std::hash Specialization Duplicate Symbol Error

Tags: c++, templates, linker, template-specialization

I have the following code:

## In Foo.h:

```
# pragma once
struct Foo {
    std::string a, b;
private:
    // some method declaration
}

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<Foo> {
         size_t operator()(const Foo &foo) const;
    }
}
```

## In Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
namespace std {
    size_t hash<Foo>::operator()(const Foo &foo) const {
        // calculate and return hash value.
    }
}
```

## In Bar.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
void func() {
    // use Foo as key of std::unordered_map
}
```

After compilation, I always got linker error: **duplicate symbol #$%Foo@#$* in: Foo.cpp.o, Bar.cpp.o**

I spent a lot of time on this, but still couldn't figure out why. I would really appreciate if anybody can help me out. I also got another question, can anybody use forward declared type to specialize a template? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are placing your code in the std namespace. This is not a very good idea. Only the standard library should be in the std namespace. Also looks like you are missing [Include Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and that can cause problems very much like what you report here.

Comment: @user4581301 I have the include guard added in the original file. Plus, adding template specialization is not "not a very good idea". Please refer to the exceptions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: I stand down on the namespacing and the include guard could not be your problem as there was no possibility of a repeated include in the provided code. In fact I cannot reproduce with the provided code, original or edited. I think you might have left something important out of your example.

Comment: @user4581301, I'm building a shared library with these files and yes, you're right, this example is a simplified version and there might be some other issues. But given I'm not using duplicate translation units and having header guard added, I really wonder what could the problem be. I've also double checked the build setup, it looks fine.